About Sample Curve Node. What exactly does it output?
I was trying to understand what a sample curve node does. I read the official docs. Watched a few videos on sample curve node(There's only one video specifically about sample curve that I could find on youtube).
However, I'm still not able to figure out what exactly it does. I could understand that it takes sample from a location on the curve, but how do I see what that location is, that i don't understand. I understand that I can use either factor or length. Also, the sample curve node interpolates once it has taken some value. But I can still not mentally visualize as to what exactly are the output from this node.
Can someone kindly explain the intricacies of this node and the various options that this node gives. Or maybe direct me to a relevant video on youtube.

Really great question. I think this type of questions are really useful for the community. I attempted to give an answer, but if something is still not clear it would be great if you let me know in the comments, I'll try to edit and clarify further.

Can someone kindly let me know how to actually view the output of an option in the sample curve node, such as how do i see what is the normal to a curve, when i choose the normal option of the sample curve node, or for that matter, how do i actually see the tangent to a curve when i choose the tangent option of the sample curve node.

I edited my answer, hopefully that helps.

It samples something along a curve. So let's say I have a curve and I sample a position(use the position output of the node), I can then use that position for something. The factor determines where along the curve to sample 0 being the start and 1 being the end of the curve, but you can switch to Length mode and then sample at certain length from the start. Let's see something visual:

As you can see "Curve Index" is actually spline index. Curve objects can have multiple disconnected segments, that's what they are - splines, index chooses which one you sample. If you check All Curves check box, the factor will go through all the splines at once - so 0 would be start of the first spline and 1 would be the end of the last spline in the curve.
As you can see the node has some other outputs. Tangent and Normal are probably easy to understand, but there is also the "Value". Value output samples something else that is plugged into Value input. So for example you could plug Curve Tilt into value, set it to Float since that's what tilt is and this way you can sample it at some point on the curve:

It's shown in degrees to the user in the UI, but saved in radians internally, that's why the values differ. You could sample named attributes that you store yourself this way as well.
You can view outputs of nodes in various ways. You can just connect them to something like in my examples I connect position to a Set Position node to move a sphere and tilt output to eventually make curve text out of it, or you can also use the viewer node by  Ctrl  +  Shift  + clicking on nodes. You have to connect the geometry you want to view attributes on and then the attribute you want to view. The values will be converted to RGB and displayed as color on the geometry if possible(if in (0,1) range). You can also enable Attribte Text overlay in the Overlays menu to show the actual numbers:

Here is how the values look converted to color:

I also added a single point to see the position. It's a single value in this case, not a field, so it gets repeated at all points. Different values matching the point would be displayed for fields.

Thank you very much for replying with such a thorough answer. It was very helpful. I replicated all the things that you explained. When i tried to add another bezier curve to the scene, the curve index did not take that into account. On the left side panel (under the Geometry nodes tab), the spline is still showing as 1 even when i have two splines in the scene. And this is causing to not letting me able to use the curve index option in the sample curve node. Could you kindly explain how to use sample index node when more than two bezier curves are added in the scene.

I'll just answer here as it has more to do with curves in general and not the node. Splines are part of same curve object. If you enter edit mode of a curve object and let's say select all points(a) and duplicate(shift+d) you are left with two segments in the same curve object. That's what I did in my screenshots, and I also revered the direction of one spline by selecting any part of one of the splines and choosing Switch Direction from right-click context menu.

Can you kindly let me know how to actually view the output of an option in the sample curve node, such as how do i see what is the normal to a curve, when i choose the normal option of the sample curve node, or for that matter, how do i actually see the tangent to a curve when i choose the tangent option of the sample curve node.

Method for Sampling Input

If you choose Factor, it will multiply your "Factor" by spline(s)* length, and use that in the "Length" mode, that is, the following setups are equivalent (hiding most sockets as whatever you connect to the hidden sockets, it won't change this equivalency):

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
As well as in the "All Curves" mode the following setups are equivalent:

Imgur mirror
* - BTW, "spline" and "curve" are terms used interchangeably in Blender. Sometimes "curve" means the entire splines collection, but sometimes it just means a single spline. "Curve Length" node gives you the total length of all splines (the sum of spline lengths).
Poly Curve Anatomy
Before I can explain how the curve is sampled, I need to also explain what a curve even is:

Every curve is internally just an ordered list (array) or points with various properties.
A Poly curve simply connects the points with straight lines, treating points as vertices connected with edges.
Of course not all possible connections between points are made, just each non-last point $n$ with the next $n+1$.
A "cyclic" curve also connects the last point with the first point.
The spline length is just the sum of the lengths of all those connections (edges).
As a result, switching "cyclicity" changes spline length:


Imgur mirror
Non-poly Curve Anatomy
Blender displays every curve using vertices and edges. Therefore it can't display actual curving lines. Instead Blender calculates positions for a number of virtual/internal/implicit points, however you want to call it, this number depending on the spline resolution. You can see this when you zoom on any curve, and/or when you have too tight of a bend compared to the resolution.
When Blender calculates length of any spline, or samples any spline, it uses its internal poly curve representation.
Finding the attribute on the spline.
Knowing the above facts, the algorithm is simple:

If using the factor, recalculate it into the length, as explained in the first section.
Travel through the internal poly representation of the spline, starting at the first point and "Distance traveled" equal zero.
Whenever you're about to travel through an edge, add edge length to "Distance traveled so far" and save it as "Next distance traveled".
If "Next distance traveled" is not greater than "length" you're sampling, then rename "Next distance traveled" to "Distance traveled so far", travel the edge to the next point and repeat point 3.
If "Next distance traveled" is greater than "length", you found the edge on which you will be sampling the value.
Subtract "Distance traveled so far" from the "length" and name the result "ratio". Consider how if both "Distance..." and "length" are equal, "ratio" will become exactly zero, whereas the maximum* "ratio" you can get is the length of the edge.
Divide "ratio" by edge length, now it truly is a ratio, in range $0...1$.
Now whatever attribute you're sampling is the linear interpolation between the 1st and 2nd points of the edge, described by formula $(1-t)A + tB$, where $t$ is the "ratio":


Imgur mirror
* - factor/length is clamped to maximum (1 for factor, spline/s length for "length"), source: source/blender/nodes/geometry/nodes/node_geo_curve_sample.cc - thanks Stef!

About sampling outside the curve length, the sampling length is clamped between 0 and the total curve length (from source code: source/blender/nodes/geometry/nodes/node_geo_curve_sample.cc). So it behaves like a constant extrapolation for out of bounds sampling lengths.

Thank you for replying with such a detailed and thorough explanation. I've gone through your answer, more than once. I tried parts of it, and experimented with the understanding that i gained from your answer. However, I think, if you could make a youtube video about it, then beginner people like me would definitely benefit a lot from awesome answers like the one that you posted above.
